# Unity 3D sound questions

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, 3d

[image]

The way the scene is set up, the ocean is basically the entire map and an island goes on top of it (basically there's a ocean level so ponds can get formed if the ground goes down far enough).  I want to add 3D sound so when you get close to the water it plays ocean sounds.  Problem is it seems the audio source component wont let me do what I want.  Is there a way to change the shape of the outline?  right now its a sphere can it by chance be a box?

Or is my entire scene setup wrong?

Comment: It can't be a box as it simply uses the distance (aka sphere radius) .. you could have a controller that simply calculates a volume falloff based on the player's height which would equal using a box ... however you still would also need to somehow check if there is ground below you otherwise you also would hear the ocean when standing on a 10cm high ground isle ;)

Comment: One other way is to do a SphereCast/BoxCast around the player and when the player is in a radius of the ocean sound, play the ocean sound using `audioSource.Play()`.

Comment: You could also just place a bunch of ocean audio sources at the perimeter of the island.

Comment: @Voidsay that crossed my mind but the island is random each time, sometimes the audio sources would be to close/to far

Comment: @MatthewZ in this case you could automate the placement by making it part of your generation algorithm. To me the screenshot looks like some Perlin noise on a regular mesh, so a rough rule could be: If y approximately (sea level - 10) and distance to closest audio source > 50 then place source with ocean audio at x y+10 z.